# Examples with hierarchical connectors

Tags: modelica

I'm getting to understand about hierarchical connectors in Modelica. Are there any libraries with examples involving hierarchical connectors (connector within a connector)? I've gone few websites looking for it and couldnt find much information. Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are examples of this in the Modelica Standard Library:

- [Modelica.Electrical.MultiPhase.Interfaces.Plug](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Electrical.MultiPhase.Interfaces.TwoPlug.html)
- [Modelica.Electrical.QuasiStationary.MultiPhase.Interfaces.Plug](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Electrical.QuasiStationary.MultiPhase.Interfaces.Plug.html)
- [Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Interfaces.FlangeWithBearing](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Interfaces.FlangeWithBearing.html)

---

A closely related concept is `expandable connector`. Here are some examples of this:

- Modelica Standard Library: [Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage.html)
- Book section: http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/thermal_control/
- The [VehicleInterfaces libarary](https://github.com/modelica/VehicleInterfaces) uses them extensively.

Comment: No, connectors like these
`connector HierarchicalConn

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y;

end HierarchicalConn;`